# Benchmark about quality levels in car parts

Tags: honda, civic, parts

I want to replace a front grille of Honda Civic 2014 EX Sedan (4 doors).

I've been suggested to buy it from this auto part dealer [RockAuto](http://www.rockauto.com/en/moreinfo.php?pk=4893525&cc=3306145&jsn=403&jsn=403) which has a great catalog.

I found the part in "CAPA" and "Economy line" in stock. I would really like to buy an OEM but they don't have it and other websites including ebay sell the OEM for 300$. So expensive. So, I'm pretty close to buy the grille in the CAPA version, but how close/far it is from the OEM version?

Does anyone have a feedback of this kind of quality levels? Real pros and cons. Suggestions?

This is part number 71121 TR3 A010 M1, just in case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used aftermarket grilles on several trucks and cars, I see no difference in quality even after years of service.

Comment: @Moab, Thanks for your answer. Very appreciated. So could you tell that "economy line" would be completely fine even if the supplier remarks the less durable?

Comment: I'd avoid cheap ebay versions. I've only tried it once and the fit was terrible. Have you tried looking on your local craigslist, forums, or a scrap yard? Scrap yard would be a long shot since your car is so new, but you could get lucky.

Comment: Fit and finish is important, cheap knock offs do not fit well and the finish falls off after a year or 2 of weather.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the part you are buying is CAPA Certified, you can be guaranteed it will have the same level of fit and finish as an OEM part.

[Certified Auto Parts Association (CAPA)](http://www.capacertified.org/) is an independent testing organization which does just that for vehicle parts. As long as it is certified, you are guaranteed the part will work just like the original. All you have to do is look for the CAPA seal:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this. Learned something very helpful today.